# Kibana dev tools undo a PUT request

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I accidently updated a record with wrong data, by using Kibana dev tools.
May I know is there anyway to revert it ? Or see the past record ?

```
PUT /_security/role_mapping/mapping-name
{
```

Comment: I think there is no way to revert it back. If you have same data in any other environment db hope you get it from there and update the record

Comment: Can I see the history like maybe in an activity log ? Does that sort of a mechanism is available in Kibana?

Comment: There is an activty log in kibana  but whatever you updated with the body that won't be available even in those logs

Comment: Do you have a snapshot (i.e. backup) of the `.security` index?

Comment: @Val Luckily , I had a recent back up so no damage was done. Thank you.